# Gulp how to write path's?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I am using gulp and I am confused that after build all my paths are wrong.

For Example :

```
SRC : 

pages -> home.html, buy.html  (src="../assets/img/test/test.png" used to get all images)
partials -> navigation.html, footer.html
assets -> js,scss,img folders
layouts -> layout.html
```

After buiild :

```
DIST : 

assets -> js,css,img folders
home.html (with ../assets.... url's) - dont work, wrong path
buy.html (with ../assets.... url's) - dont work, wrong path
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paths in gulpfile.js should look like that:

```js
'use strict'

var gulp = require('gulp')
var fontmin = require('gulp-fontmin')
// ...

gulp.task('fonts:parent', function () {
    return gulp.src('./builder/site/parent/fonts/**/*.ttf')
        .pipe(fontmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./final/frame/themes/gate/assets/fonts'))
});

// Watch
gulp.task('gulp:watch', [
  'fonts:parent',
  ], function() {
  gulp.watch('./builder/site/parent/fonts/**/*.ttf', ['fonts:parent'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['gulp:watch'])
```

/test.png versus /*.png check only test.png and not all images.

Comment: Note: /fonts/**/*.tff will check all folders and tff fonts in the fonts folder.